# Why didn't Hannah notice this?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

Just finished watching Netflix's *Dark*. I couldn't find answers for this, how is it that?

Hannah in 2019 could not spot that Mikkel is exactly the same as how her husband Michael looked like in 1986?

Comment: The same as Marty's parents not recognizing that their son is the same as the boy that introduced them

Comment: @Moondane Err who is Marty here ?

Comment: Sorry, i meant Marty McFly from "Back to the future"

Comment: Oh ok ! yea even that movie had some holes here and there, but in Season 2 Dark, I think they show Hannah having a deja vu moment when she meets Mikkel with Ulrich before the birthday bash or something.

Comment: Why did'nt grown-up-Katharina spot him on 1986 picture in her school?

Comment: Related: [Why don't Marty's parents ever mention how similar he looks to the Marty of 1955?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61/1006)

Comment: @Ivana In Season 3, Katharina does recognize Mikkel in one of the old school photographs when she investigates the whole thing.

Answer (score 5):

If we assume that they were living in the same village all these years, Hannah would probably know Mikkel since his birth, when he would definitely wouldn't look like Michael. Then he would grow up, gradually changing to be more and more like the kid she met at 1986, but for her he would always be "Mikkel". She would never have thought that "this kid looks familiar" because she already knows him. Even if she would think that he looks like her husband when he was young, then she would think that it is just a funny coincidence.

Or... **plot twist!**
She saw the resemblance and she thinks that he is the son of her husband and that's why she wants Ulrich so much, to avenge Katharina for sleeping with her husband.

Comment: Mikkel is not Michael's son. Jonas is song of Mikkel/Michael. Your answer doesnt make any sense and I wonder people who voted up.

Comment: The answer was given a year before the second season was released. At that point there was no solid evidence who **Mikkel's** father is. It could be anybody. Since we are watching a sci-fi series it could also be **himself**. This is just a speculation of course and I wrote it just to add some spice to the answer that lies above.

Comment: LOL. You need to rewatch season 1 man. It already explained in season 1 that mikkel is michael.

Comment: @SaadAnees I am not sure if you get the answer. In the first season it is shown that Mikkel is the son of Ulrich and Katharina. That doesn't necessarily mean that Ulrich is the **biological father** of Mikkel. Since this is a **sci-fi** series **anything might be possible**. So, to spice up my answer, I gave a possible scenario that **Mikkel/Michael** went to the past had sex with **Katharina** and gave birth to **himself**. Again, the answer to the question lies **above** the assumed plot and is a very valid answer to the question.

Comment: you are overthinking. Its sci-fi and it doesn't mean anything possible at anytime. There is always a foundation for any kind of plot. Your scenario is wrong. Mikkel/michael couldn't have sex with Katharina because he knew he traveled back in time. In 1986 Katharina is an adult and Mikkel and Hannah are not. By the time Mikkel becomes adult, Katharina is married to Ulrich and gave birth to their first child. Mikkel is the third child of Khathrina and Ulrich so Why would Mikkel/Michael would have sex with his mother at the first place? He was only one to know the truth at the first place.

Comment: You just cant declare your answer a valid answer by yourself.  You seem so overconfident to me and overthinker. Sorry.

Comment: @SaadAnees Again, the question is `Hannah in 2019 could not spot that Mikkel is exactly the same as how her husband Michael looked like in 1986?` and the answer to it lies on the first paragraph of my answer. The rest is just **some hypothetical nonsense to spice up my answer**. You just gave a very big extend to a simple hypothesis.

Comment: Why don't you edit this answer, as the first part is correct and a good reply to the original question?

Comment: @Chaotic is the second part that confusing that has to be removed?

Comment: I edited to remove the last bit because it's just not true after watching all seasons.

Comment: @SaadAnees: I think you're misreading what this answer is saying. It's not saying that adult Mikkel fathered young Mikkel (i.e. himself). Instead, the suggestion here is that Hannah at some point notices the similarity between 2019 Mikkel and the what Michael looked like in 1986 when she met him; but instead of taking this as proof that Michael is Mikkel, she instead _thinks_ that Mikkel is the child that was conceived by Michael sleeping with Katharina (i.e. he cheated on Hannah). If that's what she believes, it could explain why she seeks out Ulrich for an affair, as retaliation.

Comment: @SaadAnees: Just to be clear, I don't personally subscribe to the retaliation affair theory; but I do think it's an interesting thing to point out that even if you notice the similarity between two people that you don't suddenly think that they are the same person when you have no concept of time travel and it's way easier to either attribute this to coincidence or extramarital affairs as opposed to rewriting the laws of the universe.